# Fetch Black Berry 10 Call History

Tags: blackberry-10

i want to write an application to fetch call history from a black berry 10.
Can any body guide me which API i can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using the invocation framework work for what you are trying to do? It seems there is a way to fetch the call log.

https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/device_platform/invocation/phone.html

Answer (score 2):

From the above link we can only display the default call log.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [CallHistoryService](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__pim__phone__callhistoryservice.html) API available in OS 10.3.0

Here is some sample code to fetch all calls and output the numbers to the log:

```
    CallHistoryService callHistoryService;

    // The ID of a valid account is required
    bb::pim::account::Account defaultAccount =
                              callHistoryService.defaultAccount();

    // The default filter will return all calls
    CallHistoryFilter defaultFilter;

    // Contact search can be used to identify the contacts
    CallHistoryParam callHistoryParams;
    callHistoryParams.setContactSearchEnabled(false);

    QList<CallEntryResult> callHistoryResults =
                           callHistoryService.callHistory(
                               defaultAccount.id(),
                               defaultFilter,
                               callHistoryParams);


    foreach (const CallEntryResult &callEntryResult, callHistoryResults) {
        CallEntry callEntry = callEntryResult.call();
        qDebug << "Phone number: " << callEntry.phoneNumber();
    }
```